# Why does `Object.prototype.toString.call(null)` work in non-strict mode?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Why would the following be the result in ES5 non-strict mode?

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(null);
=> [object Null]
```

given that

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(window);
=> [object global]
```

Shouldn't the two lines be identical in non-strict mode, since `someFunction.call(null)` should be equivalent to `someFunction()` which should be equivalent to `someFunction.call(window)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to ES5, when [entering function code](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3) in non–strict mode:

> Else if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object.

so yes, it seems that `this` should default to the global object. **But** in [§15.3.4.4 Function.prototype.call](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4) there is:

> The thisArg value is passed without modification as the this value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a undefined or null thisArg is replaced with the global object and ToObject is applied to all other values and that result is passed as the this value.

Finally:

> [15.2.4.2 Object.prototype.toString ()](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2)
>
> When the toString method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> ```
> If the this value is undefined, return "[object Undefined]".
> If the this value is null, return "[object Null]".
> ```

Comment: This applies only to the normal method call, when you use the `call` method you are explicitly setting the `this` object, that is the very reason for the `call` method. So I think the results shown in the question are correct.

Comment: `(function() { console.log(this); }).call(null);` outputs `window`. The `call` method does not override the non-strict mode rules.

Comment: @HBP—fixed. Note to self: check the spec first.

Comment: In any ES5 browser in non-strict mode, `call(null)` on any function other than `Object.prototype.toString` runs in the context of the `window` object. (*Disclaimers:* By "any browser" I mean "tested in latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari". By "any function" I mean "any function I have tried".)

Comment: It may be nitpicking, but not happy because according to the rules posted so far for running a function in non-strict mode, "if thisArg is null or undefined, set the ThisBinding to the global object." That happens *before* the function is executed. Therefore, when `toString` is executed, `this` should never be `null`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @NathanWall—I think the difference is that in ES3, `null` was converted to `global` before entering the function, in ES5 it happens after entering the function. So `toString` gets to choose what it does with it (since it's a built-in method and can do whatever the spec says it can do). And yes, it does seem inconsistent with [§10.4.3](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3), but it does what it's specified to do.

Comment: Those statements are inconsistent, but it makes a lot of sense now. Now i see why my answer was not appropriate.

Comment: I tested another built-in: `window[0] = 'a'; window[1] = 'b'; window.length = 2; Array.prototype.slice.call(null);` throws an error "Can't convert null to object." So I guess you're right. Built-ins are different from user-defined functions, as they can be called on `null`.

Comment: @NathanWall—I think the key is that `Function.prototype.call` calls the internal `[[Call]]` method of the related object. It's that internal method that decides what to do with the supplied `this` object. [§13.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1) describes the internal `[[Call]]` method for Function objects, but Array.prorotype.slice isn't a function object, it's a built–in method, see [§8.6.2 Object Internal Properties and Methods](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2). I don't see where the internal `[[Call]]` is described.

Comment: @RobG The specified chapter 15 behavior of the built-in methods is the definition of each method's [[Call]] behavior. The 4th from the end paragraph of the intro to section 15 hints at that but isn't clear enough. The ES6 spec. draft adds "The behavior specified in this clause for each built-in function is the specification of the [[Call]] internal method behavior for that function."

Comment: @AllenWirfs-Brock—that part of [§15](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15) does not seem relevant, it's just defining what is meant by "called as a function". The `[[Call]]` in [§13.2.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1) is for "Function objects" (note capitalisation), whereas built–in methods are called "function Objects", note the different captialisation. A "function Object" is any object that is callable, whereas a "Function object" is an instance created by the Function constructor. Perhaps internal methods of built–ins are in strict mode?